# Is "healthierly" a word? As in "I've been eating healthierly lately"

Tags: adverbs, comparatives

I've been hearing people say:

> I've been eating healthier lately.

This sounds like bad grammar to me.  The word "healthier" is an adjective, so it should modify a noun, but in this sentence, the speaker is using it to modify the verb "eating".  That makes me think that the speaker should turn "healthier" into an adverb by adding "-ly", but the result doesn't sound right to me either:

> I've been eating healthierly lately.

I thought that maybe using "healthily" with "more" would sound better, but that also doesn't sound right:

> I've been eating more healthily lately.

I think this is grammatically correct, but it seems that I'm going out of my way to be correct.  I don't like that either.  The only alternative I can find is to scrap "health" completely and replace it with a synonym:

> I've been eating more nutritionally lately.

What do you think?

Comment: healthily…more healthily

Comment: [Healthy](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/healthy) is an adverb already.

Comment: Surely 'healthy' is an adjective? 'More healthily' would be the correct choice.

Comment: @Laurel, so should it be `I've been eating more healthy lately`?

Comment: @user2023861 yes that is acceptable to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "nutritional" is an adjective, so you can make it an adverb ("nutritionally").

"Healthily" is already an adverb (as conjugated from the adjective "healthy") and therefore should not be conjugated into an adverb a second time.

Let's take the adverb "nutritionally" and apply the same logic:

> I've been eating nutritionalier lately.

This has the same problem.

I recommend one of the following:

- > I've been eating healthier lately.
- > My eating has been healthier lately.
- > I've been eating more healthily lately.